# I'm searching for a reliable CSS parser / manipulator in PHP

Tags: php, css-parsing

I'm working on a project where a user can edit a CSS-file. However, we need to set some rules that must not be overwritten. Using the `!important` rule would be one way to do this, but in  a worst-case-scenario, the user could overwrite that too by simply using `!important` himself. So our general idea is to find a parser that let's us *understand* the user's CSS and put our style-definitions where they are needed.

Now we have found some parsers, but we *feel* that parsing CSS-code can be tricky — we don't know if library X does its job well. So our question is if someone already has experience with a CSS-parser and can recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

[csspurify](https://github.com/ajcrites/csspurify) may at least be able to get you started on what you want to do.  It's a CSS parser that lets you filter out rulesets and rules.  It's relatively new, but it may at least give you a jumping off point.